# Equivalent definitions of perfect field

Tags: field-theory

**Definition 1:** Let $k$ be a field. It is called perfect  field, if $\text{char} \ k=0$ or $\text{char} \ k=p$ with $k^p=k$.

**Definition 2:** $k$ has no properly bigger purely inseparable extension.

These definitions are equivalent.

**Proof:** $1 \Rightarrow 2$

If $\text{char} \ k=0$ I don't know what to do.

If $\text{char} \ k=p$. Suppose that exists an extension $E$ of $k$ which is properly bigger and is purely inseperable. Take $\alpha\in E$ such that $\alpha\notin k$. Then $\alpha^{p^n}\in k$ for some $n\geq 1$. Since $k=k^p$ then $\alpha^{p^n}=\beta_1^p$ for $\beta_1\in k$. Hence by freshman's dream $(\alpha^{p^{n-1}}-\beta_1)^p=0$  and $\alpha^{p^{n-1}}=\beta_1$ and if we continue in this way we get $\alpha^p=\beta_{n-1}\in k$ and $\beta_{n-1}=\beta_n^p$ for $\beta_n\in k$. Hence $\alpha^p=\beta_n^p$ and $(\alpha-\beta_n)^p=0$ so $\alpha=\beta_n\in k$ which is contradiction because $\alpha \notin k$.

$2 \Rightarrow 1$ Unfortunately I don't know how to prove this direction. I have tried by contradiction but it was useless.

Can anyone show how to prove it, please?

**EDIT:** An algebraic extension $E$ over $k$ is called purely inseparable if any of the following is true:

1) $[E:k]_s=1$.

2) All elements of $E$ are purely inseparable over $k$.

3) For any $\alpha\in E$, $\text{Irr}(\alpha,k,X)=X^{p^d}-a$ with $a\in k$, $d\geq 0$.

4) $E$ is generated over $k$ by a (possibly infinite) family $\{\alpha_i\}$ of elements all purely inseparable over $k$.

Comment: See [these notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/perfect.pdf).

Comment: @Servaes, Thanks for link! I have already look at this before I opened this question. I did not find anything which is similar to definition 2.

Comment: Of these definition of a purely inseparable extension, only $3$ does not rely on other definitions not given (what is $[E:k]_s$? When is an element purely inseparable?). But how should definition $3$ be interpreted if $\operatorname{char}k=0$? I assume that there $p=\operatorname{char}k$.

Comment: @Servaes, $[E:k]_s$ is separability degree. We call that element $\alpha$ is purely inseparable over $k$ if $\alpha^{p^n}\in k$ for some $n\geq 0$ (in this case characteristic is prime number).

Comment: Ok, and what about $\operatorname{char}k=0$?

Comment: @Servaes, In all those definitions it is assumed that characteristic is prime number. These definitions are from Lang's book

Comment: If definition $2$ does not apply when $\operatorname{char}k=0$, then the two definitions cannot be equivalent. If everything is restricted to fields of positive characteristic, then the two are equivalent, and I have updated my answer with an outline of a proof.

Comment: @Servaes, Thanks i'll take a look at your answer. Could we extend definition 2 for any characteristic?

Comment: Yes; commonly a polynomial $f\in R[X]$ is called *separable* if $(f,f')=R[X]$, i.e. if the ideals generated by $f$ and $f'$ are coprime. This definition is used for commutative unital rings in general. An element of an extension is called *separable* if its minimal polynomial is separable, and an extension is called separable if all its elements are separable.

Comment: That is to say; your definition $2$ in itself is fine. The problem is with the definition of *purely inseparable* in your edit. It makes much more sense (to me) to call an extension *purely inseparable* if all the elements of the extension are not separable, in the sense of my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

[Original answer below, answer to edited question first]

As definition $2$ does not apply to fields $k$ with $\operatorname{char}k=0$, the two definitions cannot be equivalent. If definition $1$ is considered only for fields of positive characteristic, then the two are equivalent. That is to say; for a field $k$ of positive characteristic $p$, the following two definitions are equivalent:

**Definition 1:** The field $k$ is called *perfect* if $k^p=k$.

**Definition 2:** The field $k$ is called *perfect* if it has no proper purely inseparable extension.

Your proof of the implication $1\ \Rightarrow\ 2$ is fine, though you might want to emphasize at the very start that you are assuming $k^p=k$. For a cleaner argument, you could work with the *minimal* $n\geq1$ such that $\alpha^{p^n}\in k$ to arrive at your conclusion more quickly.

For the converse, if $k$ has no purely inseparable extension then $X^{p^d}-a$ is reducible for all $a\in k$ and all $d\geq0$. In particular $X^p-a$ is reducible for every $a\in k$, where $X^p-a=(X-\alpha)^p$ for some $\alpha$ in a splitting field of $X^p-a$. This means $(X-\alpha)^m\in k[x]$ for some $0<m<p$. The coefficient of $X^{m-1}$ is $-m\alpha$ where $-m$ is a unit in $k$, and so we see that $\alpha\in k$. This proves that $k=k^p$.

---

Here is an outline of the proof of the contrapositive, where $k$ is a field:

If $k$ has a proper purely inseparable extension, then there exists an irreducible inseparable polynomial $f\in k[X]$. Then $f'=0$ so $\operatorname{char}k=p$ for some prime number $p$, and $f(X)=g(X^p)$ for some $g\in k[X]$. If $k^p=k$ then all coefficients of $g$ are $p$-th powers, so $f(X)=g(X^p)$ is a $p$-th power, contradicting the irreducibility of $f$. Hence $k^p\neq k$.

For the converse; if $\operatorname{char}k=p$ and $k^p\neq k$ then for every $a\in k-k^p$ the polynomial $f=x^p-a\in k[x]$ is irreducible and inseparable.

---

Note that a field $k$ has an inseparable extension if and only if there exists an irreducible inseparable polynomial $f\in k[x]$. This brings your definition $2$ in accordance  with definition $1$ of [these notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/perfect.pdf).

Comment: So you proved both directions, right?

Comment: Yes; first I prove that *if* the field isn't perfect by definition $2$, then it isn't perfect by definition $1$. The last sentence suggests a proof for the converse.

Comment: What about proof which I suggested? I think it is also correct

Comment: Yes, that argument also works. Note that for $\operatorname{char}k=0$ there is really nothing to prove; every polynomial in $f\in k[x]$ is separable because $f'\neq0$ and hence $(f,f')=k[x]$.

Comment: But see you are using another definition of perfect field. For example, look at the first sentence of second paragraph. How did you get that such polynomial exists? It seems quite weird and I guess you using something which I am not familiar.

Comment: What is your definition of a separable extension?

Comment: But we are talking about purely inseparable extension!

Comment: Ok, what is your definition of a purely inseparable extension then?

Comment: look at my edit, please

Comment: I cannot understand how did you get $X^{p^d}-a$ is reducible for any $a\in k$ and $d\geq 0$? I know that you used negation of definition 3 which I gave. But it seems very weird!

Comment: Well if it's irreducible, then $k[X]/(X^{p^d}-a)$ is a purely inseparable extension. This may require some verification, depending on how much theory you've developed already. And it *is* weird; it's my stubborn attempt to fit a (imho) weird definition into a sensible perspective.

Comment: Hi! Sorry could you help with this question, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159903/problem-from-langs-book-algebra

Answer (score 1):

There is no inseparable element over a field of characteristic $0$. So we can reduce to fields of characteristic $p>0$.

Suppose $k^p=k$ and let $E$ be a purely inseparable extension field of $k$. Take $a\in E\setminus k$ such that its minimal polynomial has minimal degree, say $X^{p^e}-b$, with $b\in k$ and $e\ge1$; since $k^p=k$, we get that $b=c^p$ and this is a contradiction, because
$$
X^{p^e}-b=(X^{p^{e-1}}-c)^p
$$
is reducible.

Conversely, suppose $b\in k\setminus k^p$. Then the polynomial has multiple roots by the derivative test; let $a$ be a multiple root in some extension field $E$, so $X^p-b=(X-a)^mf(X)$, with $m>1$ the multiplicity of the root $a$, so $f(a)\ne0$. The derivative is then
$$
0=m(X-a)^{m-1}f(X)+(X-a)^mf'(X)=(X-a)^{m-1}(mf(X)+(X-a)f'(X))
$$
As $m>1$, we conclude that $mf(X)+(X-a)f'(X)=0$. If $m<p$, we can evaluate at $a$ and get $mf(a)=0$, contradicting $f(a)\ne0$. Hence $m=p$, which means $X^p-b=(X-a)^p$. A factorization of $X^p-b$ over $k[X]$ must then have the form $(X-a)^{n_1}(X-a)^{n_2}\dots(X-a)^{n_r}$. Take $n=\min\{n_1,\dots,n_r\}$ and suppose $n<p$ (that is, that $X^p-b$ is not irreducible). Then
$$
(X-a)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}(-1)^ja^{n-j}X^j\in k[X]
$$
Since $n<p$, $\binom{n}{n-1}(-1)^j\ne0$ in $k$, so $a\in k$. Contradiction to $b\notin k^p$.

The extension $k(a)$ is inseparable and has degree $p$, so it is purely inseparable.